# problems with file directory ftp

Tags: html, ftp

i'm new in using hosting, i have a question about a FTP, why if i upload something (for example a image) to my server i cannot see it from the browser using the directory for example (http://www.mywebsite.com/public_html/images/backgrounds/background.png) if i use that address i get a fil with a "?" sign instead of the image. the only way to see the image is changing http by ftp for example,(ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/public_html/images/backgrounds/background.png)

please how to find the files with http instead of ftp, to be able to use it in my web page using html

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the publichtml folder is the root of your domain, which is to say that http://www.mywebsite.com/ points to your/relative/path/to/publichtml/

Using your example of putting a file at /publichtml/images/backgrounds/background.png would mean it should be accessible at http://www.mywebsite.com/images/backgrounds/background.png

Similarly, if you put filename.html in the /publichtml/ folder of your server, you should be able to access it at http://www.mywebsite.com/filename.html - If you put it in a subfolder of /publichtml/, say, at publichtml/example/, it should be accessible at http://www.mywebsite.com/example/filename.html

This can very from one server to another, but in most situations, this is common practice.

Edit: broken formatting.

Comment: thank you i did that but i cannot see the images,look this is the path http://compralentes.com/backgrounds/background.png look tha image file how it look thank you

Comment: Try putting the background.png file at _public_html/backgrounds/background.png_ and then visiting [http://compralentes.com/backgrounds/background.png](http://compralentes.com/backgrounds/background.png). Does that work?